# Resetting a User's Password with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I also would like reset a user password using Microsoft Graph from a windows service using admin permissions. Using PATCH request to the user's profile
seemed promising but the required Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission is not on the list at  apps.dev.microsoft.com so I get a "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." error.

I had promised to replace PowerShell cmdlets with Microsoft Graph in our application and this small but essential feature now becomes a blocker.

Is there a plan to add this permission to the list?

Is there any way I can assign this permission? perhaps by editing the manifest? If so does anyone know the correct info

```
            "resourceAppId": "????",
             "resourceAccess": [
              {
                     "id": "????",
                      "type": "Scope"
              ,
```

What's with the office portal Azure Directory Admin, app registration (preview)? I can see the app I registered at apps.dev.microsoft.com.  Is it now an alternative to apps.dev? I like the interface better and the built-in admin consent button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no application permission (yet) that allows you to reset a user's password using Microsoft Graph.

> Is there a plan to add this permission to the list?

Yes, but that's about all there is to share, at the moment.

> Is there any way I can assign this permission?

The only way to achieve this today (2019-01-17) is to assign the "Company Administrator" role to the *ServicePrincipal* object for your app — a *very* risky move (which is not recommended), as it will give your app full admin permissions.

> What's with the office portal Azure Directory Admin, app registration (preview)? [...] Is it now an alternative to apps.dev?

Yes, though it's still in preview and it's possible some things might not work (as with all things in preview).

Comment: Microsoft Graph permissions reference clearly states the lack of Directory.AccessAsUser.All for applications. I should have read the manual.

Comment: @tom.kanaryThere is nothing clear about the docs, in this case. :)